# Mocking methods provided by OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using Moq so I cannot mock the extension methods that are heavily used with OrmLite.

I've got several classes that use `IDbConnection` and select some data our of a SQL database.

I tried just using Sqlite for the unit tests, but I am getting several failures (for obvious reasons) when trying to open a transaction. This is because the production code uses SqlServer, and I have calls to `OpenTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)`.

Reading the current release notes, it *appears* that the methods can now be intercepted by using `OrmLiteResultsFilter`. I viewed [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/MockAllApiTests.cs) link to see how the tests were being performed, but the tests are connecting to a database. I just want to isolate this out in my unit tests - connecting to an in-memory database, or not.

Am I stuck wrapping `OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi` to my own interface for the methods that I want to stub (most of the time it's `Select<T>`), or is there a facility that OrmLite will provider without having to configure a connection to a database? It would be nice if you could set the dialect provider to a `MockDialectProvider`.